# Strange encoding in PDF property fields

Tags: pdf, encoding, binary-data, utf-16

I have a question about how the document properties (Title, Author, etc.) are stored in a PDF file.  It looks like UTF-16 in big-endian byte order.

So "MyName" will be encoded as:
FE FF 00 4D 00 79 00 4E 00 61 00 6D 00 65

However, I run into this character "－" which should have value FF 0D, but I find in its place these hex number FF 5C 72

So "My－Name" looks like this:
FE FF 00 4D 00 79 FF 5C 72 00 4E 00 61 00 6D 00 65

Anybody knows why FF 5C 72 is used here?  Why 3 bytes when everywhere else is UTF-16?  Why these values?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are not interpreting correctly what you see:

1. `FE FF` is the start of a sequence.
2. `00` is a `null` byte.
3. `4D` in your case most likely translates to `M`.
4. `79` in your case most likely translates to `y`.
5. `4E` in your case most likely translates to `N`.
6. `61` in your case most likely translates to `a`.
7. `6D` in your case most likely translates to `m`.
8. `65` in your case most likely translates to `e`.

Compare this to the output of my simple `ascii` command line tool, which prints a list of all ASCII aliases as a table with their *hex* and *dec* encodings:

```
$ ascii -h
Usage: ascii [-dxohv] [-t] [char-alias...]
   -t = one-line output  -d = Decimal table  -o = octal table  -x = hex table
   -h = This help screen -v = version information
Prints all aliases of an ASCII character. Args may be chars, C \-escapes,
English names, ^-escapes, ASCII mnemonics, or numerics in decimal/octal/hex.

Dec Hex    Dec Hex    Dec Hex  Dec Hex  Dec Hex  Dec Hex   Dec Hex   Dec Hex  
  0 00 NUL  16 10 DLE  32 20    48 30 0  64 40 @  80 50 P   96 60 `  112 70 p
  1 01 SOH  17 11 DC1  33 21 !  49 31 1  65 41 A  81 51 Q   97 61 a  113 71 q
  2 02 STX  18 12 DC2  34 22 "  50 32 2  66 42 B  82 52 R   98 62 b  114 72 r
  3 03 ETX  19 13 DC3  35 23 #  51 33 3  67 43 C  83 53 S   99 63 c  115 73 s
  4 04 EOT  20 14 DC4  36 24 $  52 34 4  68 44 D  84 54 T  100 64 d  116 74 t
  5 05 ENQ  21 15 NAK  37 25 %  53 35 5  69 45 E  85 55 U  101 65 e  117 75 u
  6 06 ACK  22 16 SYN  38 26 &  54 36 6  70 46 F  86 56 V  102 66 f  118 76 v
  7 07 BEL  23 17 ETB  39 27 '  55 37 7  71 47 G  87 57 W  103 67 g  119 77 w
  8 08 BS   24 18 CAN  40 28 (  56 38 8  72 48 H  88 58 X  104 68 h  120 78 x
  9 09 HT   25 19 EM   41 29 )  57 39 9  73 49 I  89 59 Y  105 69 i  121 79 y
 10 0A LF   26 1A SUB  42 2A *  58 3A :  74 4A J  90 5A Z  106 6A j  122 7A z
 11 0B VT   27 1B ESC  43 2B +  59 3B ;  75 4B K  91 5B [  107 6B k  123 7B {
 12 0C FF   28 1C FS   44 2C ,  60 3C <  76 4C L  92 5C \  108 6C l  124 7C |
 13 0D CR   29 1D GS   45 2D -  61 3D =  77 4D M  93 5D ]  109 6D m  125 7D }
 14 0E SO   30 1E RS   46 2E .  62 3E >  78 4E N  94 5E ^  110 6E n  126 7E ~
 15 0F SI   31 1F US   47 2F /  63 3F ?  79 4F O  95 5F _  111 6F o  127 7F DEL
```

Oh, surprise!

This table matches my "assumptions" from above perfectly. So you can savely re-consider your own ones about *"UTF-16 in big-endian byte order"*.

And that means for your hex number in question, **`FF 5C 72`**?!?

Well, look it up: `FF` you can skip, `5C 72` is `\r`... Which means? (Answer left as excercise to the reader)

Comment: FE FF is the Byte Order Marker (BOM) for Big-endian (BE.  Similarly, FF FE means Little-Endian).  00 4D is the encoding for "M" in UTF-16BE.  Anyway, I figured it out.  0A and 0D are special characters in a PDF stream so all occurrences of them are replace with \r and \n.  Anyway, since you are the only one to reply, yours is the answer.

Comment: @ChuBun: You can savely assume that I know the BOM for BE and FE. But there is no need to resort to it when interpreting strings in the `/Info` dictionary of a PDF like yours...

Comment: @ChuBun *Anyway, since you are the only one to reply, yours is the answer* - you shouldn't accept an answer after so short a time merely because it is the only one at the time.

Comment: @mkl: An 'accept' can be withdrawn any time, if the OP wants, and it can be assigned to a new, better, more complete answer as soon as it is there. (An 'upvote' cannot be simply withdrawn in my experience -- it will always convert into a 'downvote' if you try so. This I find a bit overshooting...)

Comment: @Kurt yes, it can be withdrawn. But still I think an accepted answer should indicate more than "no one else came up with something".